# How to modify this tetrahedron into a square pyramid?

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, geometry

I hope everyone's doing well.
I have a Java project. First I had to make a tetrahedron ( see the code below). Now I have to modify the code a little so that it shows a square pyramid but I can't seem to be able to solve it.
Any kind of help would be reallyyy appreciated:))))

```
// first class
import javax.vecmath.*;
import javax.media.j3d.*;
 public class Tetrahedron extends IndexedTriangleArray {
public Tetrahedron() {
super(4, TriangleArray.COORDINATES | TriangleArray.NORMALS, 12);
setCoordinate(0, new Point3f(1f,1f,1f));
setCoordinate(1, new Point3f(1f,-1,-1f));
setCoordinate(2, new Point3f(-1f,1f,-1f));
setCoordinate(3, new Point3f(-1f,-1f,1f));
int[] coords = {0,1,2,0,3,1,1,3,2,2,3,0};
float n = (float)(1.0/Math.sqrt(3));
setNormal(0, new Vector3f(n,n,-n));
setNormal(1, new Vector3f(n,-n,n));
setNormal(2, new Vector3f(-n,-n,-n));
setNormal(3, new Vector3f(-n,n,n));
int[] norms = {0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3};
setCoordinateIndices(0, coords);
setNormalIndices(0, norms);
}
}


// second class
import javax.vecmath.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.media.j3d.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.*;
import java.applet.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame;

public class TestTetrahedron extends Applet {
public static void main(String[] args) {
new MainFrame(new TestTetrahedron(), 640, 480);
}

public void init() {
// create canvas
GraphicsConfiguration gc =
SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
Canvas3D cv = new Canvas3D(gc);
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(cv, BorderLayout.CENTER);
BranchGroup bg = createSceneGraph();
bg.compile();
SimpleUniverse su = new SimpleUniverse(cv);
su.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
su.addBranchGraph(bg);
}

private BranchGroup createSceneGraph() {
BranchGroup root = new BranchGroup();
TransformGroup spin = new TransformGroup();
spin.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
root.addChild(spin);
// object
Appearance ap = new Appearance();
ap.setMaterial(new Material());
Shape3D shape = new Shape3D(new Tetrahedron(), ap);
// rotating object
Transform3D tr = new Transform3D();
tr.setScale(0.25);
TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup(tr);
spin.addChild(tg);
tg.addChild(shape);
Alpha alpha = new Alpha(-1, 4000);
RotationInterpolator rotator =
new RotationInterpolator(alpha, spin);
BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere();
rotator.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);
spin.addChild(rotator);
// light and background
Background background = new Background(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
background.setApplicationBounds(bounds);
root.addChild(background);
AmbientLight light = new AmbientLight
(true, new Color3f(Color.red));
light.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
root.addChild(light);
PointLight ptlight = new PointLight(new Color3f(Color.green),
new Point3f(3f,3f,3f), new Point3f(1f,0f,0f));
ptlight.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
root.addChild(ptlight);
PointLight ptlight2 = new PointLight(new Color3f(Color.orange),
new Point3f(-2f,2f,2f), new Point3f(1f,0f,0f));
ptlight2.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
root.addChild(ptlight2);
return root;
}
}
```

Thank you a lot in advance, have a nice day! :)

The modified class:

```
 import javax.vecmath.*;
 import javax.media.j3d.*;
  public class Tetrahedron extends IndexedTriangleArray {
 public Tetrahedron() {
 super(8, IndexedTriangleArray.COORDINATES | IndexedTriangleArray.NORMALS, 24);
   Point3f[] PyramidCoordinates = {
               new Point3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f),
               new Point3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f),
new Point3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f),
new Point3f(1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f),
new Point3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f),
new Point3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f),
new Point3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f),
new Point3f(1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f)};  

      Vector3f[] PyramidNormals = { new Vector3f(0f,0f,1f),
                                    new Vector3f(0f,0f,-1f),
                                    new Vector3f(1f,0f,0f),
                                    new Vector3f(-1f,0f,0f),
                                    new Vector3f(0f,1f,0f),
                                    new Vector3f(0f,-1f,0f)};

    int[] coords = {0,1,2,3,7,6,5,4,0,3,7,4,5,6,2,1,0,4,5,1,6,7,3,2};  
    int[] norms = {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5};
    setCoordinates(0, PyramidCoordinates);
    setNormals(0, PyramidNormals);
    setCoordinateIndices(0, coords);
    setNormalIndices(0, norms);
    }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what you're asking for. Perhaps is it "how to add a new vertex"?

Comment: The 3D figure should be a square pyramid which means a square base with four triangles on the sides. . The teacher said it can be done by modifying the class Tetrahedron but I don't know what to do...

Comment: `super(4...` would become `super(5 `. And you need an additional `setCoordinate` and `setNormal` and... I let to you finding the rest of needed changes.

Comment: @Ripi2 thank you very much:)

Comment: @Ripi2 I've been trying for hours but I still can't figure it out.. Could you pleasee help me a little bit more if you have time?

Comment: If you start with code that works for 4 vertices, then to update it for 5 vertices think of all things involved: mainly coordinates and normals. Other things, like lights or materials or transformations remain unchanged.

Comment: @Ripi2 I modified the class Tetrahedron and added it to my question. Idk why it doesn't show the whole pyramid (all 6 triangles) but only 2 triangles...